# What work of art is it?

Tags: riddle, visual, rebus

#### The next set of images is meant to represent a work of art. Can you find which? I give you the hint that exactly one of the images intentionally represents the opposite of what's in the work of art :)

---

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

## Hints

Alright, it's been nearly a week! Here is your first Hint:

### Hint 1 - 15th of April 2020

> I'm here specifying which type is this work of art: these images are rebus for **lyrics** of a song :) Thus, I'm adding the *Rebus* tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This work of art is:

> The song **'Life' by Des'ree**

The pictures (as indicated by the hint) represent:

> Lyrics from the song:
>
>  *I'm **afraid** of the **dark**,*
>  *Especially when I'm in a **park***
>  *And there's **no-one else around**,*
>  *Oh, I get the **shivers***...
>
>  *I don't want to see a **ghost**,*
>  *It's a sight that I fear most*;
>  *I'd rather have **a piece of toast***
>  *And watch the evening **news***...
>
>  *Life, oh life, oh life, oh life,*
>  *Doo, doot doot dooo.*

Note that as specified in the question, one picture is out of place and actually represents its opposite:

> The large crowd at a sports stadium is actually supposed to represent the line "*and there's no-one else around*"...

Comment: Nicely done! Note that I made this puzzle from 'Life' - Sorenious Bonk, it is a remake of the original you posted and they both have same lyrics, so congrats ;)